# bash sqlcmd variable array

Tags: bash, variables, sqlcmd

I´m trying to acces values in a variable I receive from an sqlcmd in a loop:

```
while read line ;do AllNumbers=`sqlcmd -h -1 -S mysqlserver.localdomain -U Me -P MyPasswd -d master -Q "SET nocount on; SELECT PHONENUMBER FROM MYTABLE WHERE USER LIKE '"$line"' " < /dev/null`; for i in "$AllNumbers"; do echo "$line $i"; done; done< mytext.txt
```

The Number of results in the variable "$AllNumbers" can be 1 to 5, and the lenght of the number can also vary.
What I get in Moment is:

John 01234567

9876543

Jack 13579024

Jim 08642135

10293847

56473829

In the end I want to have an output like:

John 01234567

John 98765432

Jack 13579024

Jim 08642135

Jim 10293847

Jim 56473829

I tried with IFS, but I´m unsure what the delimiter in the variable $AllNumber is.
If I do:

```
OneUser=`sqlcmd -h -1 -S mysqlserver.localdomain -U Me -P MyPasswd -d master -Q "SET nocount on; SELECT PHONENUMBER FROM MYTABLE WHERE USER LIKE '"Jim"' "`; echo "$OneUSer"
```

I get:

08642135

10293847

56473829

I´m glad for any hint...

Thanks in advance

Lotte

Answer (score 1):

Why not ask the database to do the hard work?

```
SELECT USER, PHONENUMBER FROM MYTABLE WHERE USER LIKE '"$line"'
```

Also, make sure you validate $line to prevent SQL injection attacks (see [Bobby Tables](https://bobby-tables.com/)).

Comment: I know, all the above is an example, in the end I need to split the content of a variable into single pieces...

Comment: It works when redirecting the output of sqlcmd to a file, get rid of the spaces and read line by line, but no luck when the output of sqlcmd delivers more than one result... I can´t see special characters inside the variable... As another try when query a sqlcmd with several SELECTS it works like charm... But in the end I want to split the output of  a resulting string...